# market place EBS volume as secondary device

Tags: centos, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I managed to lock myself out on AWS marketplace centos 6.3 server. It seems to be a permission issue (SELinux) and needs some reconfiguration. I was going to mount the root drive of the problematic instance on another running instance, but when attaching it i receive the message: 'Marketplace codes may not be attached as a secondary device'. Is there any way out?
thanks